# Android MediaPlayer pause streaming

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I am using Android MediaPlayer to stream and play my online playlist .

```
mMediaPlayer1.setDataSource(streamUrl);
mMediaPlayer1.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer1.prepareAsync();
mMediaPlayer1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){
@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
           // Play this song and prepare next song
           mp.start();
           mMediaPlayer2.setDataSource(streamUrl2);
           mMediaPlayer2.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
           mMediaPlayer2.prepareAsync();
    }
};
```

For smooth experience I am buffering the next song before finishing the current playing song. For that I starts streaming of next song just after the current song is prepared and start playing.

So the result is,it's streaming two songs at the same time. If the Internet is fast then it's working fine but if it is slow then the current playing song also stuck(because it is streaming two songs simultaneously).
I am searching for a way to pause the streaming of background song, after it gets prepared, or is their any way to just prepare the next song. Please help.

Comment: use TimerTask to manage your current playing song and download another in background and manage Timer thread according to the duration to song playing

Comment: try using Producer-Consumer like pattern ,the mediaPlayer should be buffering the audio streams, so you can try and define 2 listeners,when buffer is filled,and when updating buffer .the live stream 1 should buffer freely and when the buffer is  filled, notify stream  2 to start working, when stream 1 comes back to consume the buffer, pause stream 2 buffering , and resume stream 1 buffering, and so forth.

Comment: @shaydel is their any way to pause/start buffering in Media Player.

Comment: you can only use `onBufferingUpdate (MediaPlayer mp, int percent)` as the high level API has limited buffer handling to my knowledge, try manipulating mp(pause and etc..) using the percent value of the buffer. for example you can load 1% of stream 2 for every 5% of stream 1(assuming both use similiar buffer size,adjust accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener` ([doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener.html)) on your  `mMediaPlayer1`. After the buffering is 90%-100% (or less, depending how fast you want to start buffering your next song) then you can start preparing the second song in your `mMediaPlayer2`. This way you can avoid bad performance and start the streaming of the next song while the first song is playing, but the song 1 is already buffered. I think there is no way for pausing the stream, you can just stop it from what I know.

Comment: As I know, mp.pause() is used to pause the current playing song only,it doesn't pause streaming.

Comment: that is nice idea, but as per my requirement I want to only prepare the another song just after the first one is prepared. Because in most cases if you don't like the song then you will switch to next song within 10 sec(Possibility more than 80%). I want to handle that scenario. So if any way I could pause the buffering that will be best for the user experience, and that what I am trying to do.